# Programmatically Setting Text Shadow Properties in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

PowerPoint has two kinds of shadows - shape and text. Shape shadows may be set by right-clicking on a shape (including a text box), choosing *Format Text*, then selecting *Shadow* or using VBA via the Shadow property on each shape:

```
For Each Slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
  For Each Shape In Slide.Shapes
     Shape.Shadow.Size = 100
     ''# etc
  Next
Next
```

How do I set **text** shadow's properties using VBA? In the UI, these may be accessed by right-clicking on text, choosing *Format Text Effect*, then selecting *Shadow*. I've done a bit of digging online and have been unable to find where these properties may be accessed via PowerPoint's VBA API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want the `TextRange2` object to do so. You can get this through it's parent of `TextFrame2`. Here's an example of how you can set shadow's on text:

```
Sub setTextShadow()
Dim sh As Shape
Set sh = ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes(1)
Dim tr As TextRange2
Set tr = sh.TextFrame2.TextRange
    With tr.Font.Shadow
        .OffsetX = 10
        .OffsetY = 10
        .Size = 1
        .Blur = 4
        .Transparency = 0.5
        .Visible = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Finding the info you provided is hard. I tried a bit of Googling and couldn't come up with it.

Comment: Happy to help Ben! Note also that if you just want to use the standard text shadow (the one available from the ribbon bar), you can use the `Dim tr as TextRange` (**not** `TextRange2`), and then `Set tr = sh.TextFrame.TextRange` (**not** `TextFrame2`) and then finally just `tr.Font.Shadow = True`